# anonymous struct fail to compile with composite literal

Tags: go, struct, interface, literals, composite

Just 2 lines of code:

```
var v4 interface{}=strcut{x int}(1) // line 14
var v5 interface{}=&strcut{x int}(1) // line 15
```

Go prints:

```
my_test.go:14:29: missing ',' in composite literal
my_test.go:15:30: missing ',' in composite literal
```

So how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: strcut should be struct!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize an anonymous struct, you have to initialize the member fields of that struct:

```
var v4 interface{}=struct{x int}{x:1} // line 14
var v5 interface{}=&struct{x int}{x:1} // line 15
```

Comment: I'm using Go 1.13, still the same error after I changed to {x:1}

Comment: Works on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/MMk9VNy5FhO